# windows authentication and iOS7

Tags: ios7, windows-authentication

We are developing a web application in asp.net and HTML5 (+ offline feature) and we are using “Add to desktop” button to create the desktop application.

Before access main screen, we have a windows authentication screen, so people can connect using their domain credentials.

In safari, we have almost no problem. It's the expected behavior when we are online. For the offline mode, safari needs to keep an active tab with the website loaded to allow offline access to it, otherwise safari does not find website – even if it’s cached with cache manifest...

In the desktop application (using “Add to desktop” button), the authentication popup on the main page does not appears. When I trace the HTTP requests, I can see 2 requests with a return status of 401. When I look into the logs, safari sandbox throw an exception (twice tries then abort operation)... The screen remains blank.

any ideas anyone or any fix is planned to correct this problem ?

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Anyone else seeing this on iOS 8.0?

Comment: Hi, we are currently downloading this update. I don't think it will be the same because the updates are minors this time... I will keep you in touch soon !

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with iOS 7.  Windows Authentication only works in "Private Mode" or in another browser such as Chrome or Puffin.  However, there isn't a workaround currently available to save an app to the home screen.  Here's a thread on the Apple forums about this same issue:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5327078?start=60&tstart=0

Comment: I saw that post, I've found a workaround using Forms authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The new iOS 7.03 fixes this issue.